# Is OpenGL on macOS deprecated?

Tags: macos, opengl, glut, deprecated

I've started to get a little involved with OpenGL, but I get warnings all the time!

Why is, for example, `glutInit(&argc, arg);` deprecated in macOS 10.9?
('glutInit' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.9 - OpenGL API deprecated.)

Is there any way to **Update** OpenGl?

Comment: "Is there any way to Update OpenGl?"  Switch to something [slightly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) less [lickable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [OpenGL Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_intro/opengl_intro.html) as well as [this here](https://developer.apple.com/macos/whats-new/) (all the way at the bottom), OpenGL is a deprecated technology starting with macOS 10.14. They want you to use [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/) instead…